# I need help reversing what a function does

Tags: c++

So i have got this function.

```
UINT32 Encrypt(UINT32 instruction, int increment)
{
    UINT32 linstruction = _rotl(instruction, 7);
    UINT32 rinstruction = _rotr(instruction, 3);

    UINT32 key = (0x1F3D8AF * increment) ^ (rinstruction ^ linstruction);
    return (key ^ instruction);
}
```

I need to make a function that actually decrypts this and gets the instruction from the result using a key so it would be like.

```
t = encrypt(t, i);
t = decrypt(t, key);
```

Basically i want it to reverse the whole process of the encrypt so it decrypts it and gets me the instruction.

They are used in this function

```
int RbxOpEncoder::encode(Instruction op, int i, int key) {
    int orig = ConvertInstruction(op);
    int t = orig;
    switch (GET_OPCODE(op)) {
    case OP_JMP:
        t = ((Encrypt(t, i) & 0x3FFFFFF) | ((orig >> 26 & MASK1(6, 0)) << 0x1A));
    break;
    case OP_CALL:
    case OP_TAILCALL:
    case OP_CLOSURE:
    case OP_RETURN:
        t = ((Calldecrypt(t, i) & 0x3FFFFFF) | ((orig >> 26 & MASK1(6, 0)) << 0x1A));
        break;  
    }
    t = EncryptOpcode(t, key);
    return t;
}
```

Comment: What is the `key` provided to `decrypt` ?

Comment: its an argument in the function encrypt is used into, i edited it.

Comment: This seems like more of a mathematical or cryptology problem. Once you figure out the math, turning it into C++ code should be trivial.

Comment: It may not be as simple as reversing the process, some encryption methods work with public and private keys. You encode with a private key and decode with a public key, If you don't know what the other key is you can do one thing but you cannot do the other.

Comment: With several tries and errors, it seems I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
std::uint32_t decrypt(std::uint32_t instruction, int increment)
{
    instruction = instruction ^ (0x1F3D8AF * increment);

    for (int i = 0; i != 15; ++i) {
        instruction = Encrypt(instruction, 0);
    }
    return instruction;
}
```

And then you have

```
decrypt(Encrypt(value, increment), increment) == value
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dd26d6fd38728e1)

Comment: How in the world did you come up with that? Why 15 iterations?

Comment: @MooingDuck: That kind of function (bijection ) should have a cycle. I would expect a bigger one BTW from a encrypt method. I loop to see evolution of 1 through `Encrypt` and saw the repetition, and then check for other values up to `20000000`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It doesn't really confirm. My first version/try was `_rotr(instruction, 7) & _rotr(instruction, 3)` which worked until `1u & (1u << 3u)`.

Comment: I doesn't conclusively confirm, but integers 0-99 with increments of {prime-1, prime, prime+1} seems a fast and relatively reliable check.